# Having accepted US ID as a lawful J1 with expired visa

Tags: usa

My wife and I are non-US citizens on J-visa. We are on our lawful third year, but visa stamp expired on 1st year and we didn't renewed. Currently we can't even renew visa because of COVID-19 restrictions (consulates and embassies are all closed for that).

I, as an EAD cardholder - hence driver license as well, don't have issues to having ID accepted.
My wife otherwise is in a limbo, where event shopping a wine causes her trouble and embarrassment. She didn't get an EAD card, or any other Gov ID. Visa is an accepted way of ID, but not if expired. She currently can't get driver license or even state ID, per Rhode Island rules, even having I-94 and DS-2019.

Is there any way of getting a US ID that is widely accepted being a J-1 with expired visa stamp?

Comment: This is a horrible flaw in the implementation of Real ID. Public comments on the regulations pointed out this flaw before the regulations were adopted, but the comments were dismissed. You might try going to court to get the regulations invalidated, but this is probably not worthwhile unless you can find an immigrant advocacy group that is willing to put its weight behind the case and engage a good lawyer with expertise in the Administrative Procedure Act. Another option is to appeal to legislators to change the law itself, but that is unlikely to succeed and likely to take a long time.

Comment: @phoog This, I think would be a good answer (statibg basically that is a known  -  but ignored - problem since conception) and a link to where the public comments can be read.

Comment: @phoog: The OP's problem isn't with REAL ID regulations, because the OP isn't looking to get a REAL ID driver's license -- a non-REAL-ID driver's license is fine for driving and buying alcohol. (In fact, there are some states where they can't get a REAL ID even if they had a valid visa -- Washington state does not issue REAL ID driver's licenses to non-citizens, and Ohio does not issue REAL ID driver's licenses to non-citizens except permanent residents.)

Comment: @user102008 some states don't offer non-Real-ID licenses. Washington doesn't offer Real ID licenses, only enhanced licenses, which is why they only offer them to US citizens. Your information about Ohio seems to be incorrect, since they accept foreign passports with valid US visas: https://services.dps.ohio.gov/BMVOnlineServices/DL/AcceptableDocuments. The problem with Rhode Island is that they seem to have adopted the valid visa requirement from the Real ID regulations as a requirement for the non-Real-ID license. Perhaps the solution is to move to Connecticut and get a "drive only" license.

Comment: @phoog: Which states don't offer non-REAL-ID licenses? For Ohio, you are right. They seem to have added the foreign passport with visa option between [November](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111222609/https://services.dps.ohio.gov/BMVOnlineServices/DL/AcceptableDocuments) and [December](https://web.archive.org/web/20201207154920/https://services.dps.ohio.gov/BMVOnlineServices/DL/AcceptableDocuments).

Comment: @MarkJohnson: [Here](https://www.federalregister.gov/d/08-140) is the REAL ID final rule. The comment and response [here](https://www.federalregister.gov/d/08-140/p-325) addresses why a foreign passport is not used as an identity document and why a valid visa is used instead.

Comment: @user102008 thank you for the link, it's enlightening this passage: "These can include Forms I-797 and I-94 as they provide sufficient information for a State DMV to check SAVE"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A foreign passport is generally accepted as photo ID for most purposes in the US, including drinking alcohol and boarding flights. Does your wife not currently have a valid passport?

As for getting a Rhode Island driver's license, I believe she should be able to get a non-REAL-ID driver's license with her passport, I-94, and DS-2019. Although the [official checklist](http://www.dmv.ri.gov/documents/forms/checklist/license_checklist.pdf) does seem to require an unexpired visa when a foreign passport is used for identity document for non-REAL-ID driver's licenses, I believe that that is a mistake. (For example, it conflicts with the [main driver's license page](http://www.dmv.ri.gov/licenses/) which does not list a visa in the list of things that F-1 and F-2 people need to get a driver's license. I don't see any reason why J-1 and J-2 should be any different.) [This page](https://web.uri.edu/global/international-students/social-security-drivers-license/) from the University of Rhode Island does not mention needing a visa to get a driver's license for F-1 or J-1, though it does mention needing a letter from the university. I suggest she go to a DMV and try to apply.

Comment: You're right. My wife went to DMV with her J1 papers and her application was accepted. DMV website and even their official form checklist aren't specific. It may be that their "passport with valid visa" doesn't mean visa stamp per se, but additional docs that supports it. I can tell even by looking at several Immigration forums, that in general, this term having multiple meanings causes a lot of confusion. Also, I may be wrong, but I believe non/Real ID is not an issue, since they check docs against SEVIS anyway?